# node.js zlib deflate Invalid windowBits issue

Tags: python, node.js, zlib

I am trying to port a python script to node.js and is having trouble with the deflate method in zlib.

The python script:

```
def compressMessage(data):
    encode_message = data
    compressor = zlib.compressobj(-1, zlib.DEFLATED, 31, 8, zlib.Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY)
    compressed_data = compressor.compress(encode_message)
    compressed_data += compressor.flush()
    return compressed_data
```

And the definition of compressobj in zlib in python :

```
zlib.compressobj([level[, method[, wbits[, memlevel[, strategy]]]]])
```

[zlib.compressobj doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html)

And in node.js I tried :

```
var zlibBuffer = zlib.deflateSync(buffer, {
    windowBits: (zlib.Z_DEFAULT_WINDOWBITS + 16)
});
```

Which failed :

```
throw new Error('Invalid windowBits: ' + opts.windowBits);
```

I am wondering how to set the windowBits in node.js zlib just like I did in python.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: As the quoted docs mention, the default for wbits is 15 ... please show the output message from the throw statement,

Answer (score 0):

Use `zlib.gzipSync` instead of `zlib.deflateSync`.

Comment: This answer seems like it could do with a bit more of an explanation?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14553965)

Comment: Looks like an adequate answer to me, even though it's short enough to trigger bad reviews. OP was trying to decode a gzip datastream with a deflate decoder.

Comment: @4c74356b41 This link? It's not a link.

Comment: @IvanStarostin How does it not answer the question? It says exactly what to do to fix the problem. The stackoverflow police here can apparently be easily replaced by a script that copies and pastes in stock but irrelevant comments when an answer is less than _n_ characters in length, for some value of _n_.